# Resolve key and value of map into one big string in Java

Tags: java, html, css, string, dictionary

I'm creating a HTML table with my Java program and I’ve got a map with style parameters.
my map could look like:

```
Map<String, String> stylingParams;
index 0: key="text-align"       | value="left"
index 1: key="background-color" | value="blue"
...
```

There should be no limit on the styling params. Is there a way to create a string out of this Map that looks like this:

```
"style="text-align: left; background-color: blue;""
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: which jdk you are on? itereate through a map (run a loop) and add the key value to your string as per your separator.

Comment: I'm using java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `StringBuilder` and append, e.g.:

```
Map<String, String> styles = new HashMap<>();
styles.put("text-align", "left");
styles.put("background-color", "blue");

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : styles.entrySet()){
    stringBuilder.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    stringBuilder.append(";");
}

//Remove last ; and print
System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 1));
```

Here's Java 8 way to do it:

```
Map<String, String> styles = new HashMap<>();
styles.put("text-align", "left");
styles.put("background-color", "blue");

String styleString = styles.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));

System.out.println(styleString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (without lambdas):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> styles = new HashMap<>();
        styles.put("text-align", "left");
        styles.put("background-color", "blue");

        System.out.println(elementsToStyle(styles));
    }

    private static String elementsToStyle(Map<String, String> styles) {

        if(styles==null || styles.isEmpty())
            return "";

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("style=\"");
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : styles.entrySet()){
            stringBuilder
            .append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue())
            .append("; ");
        }

        stringBuilder.delete(stringBuilder.length()-2, stringBuilder.length());
        stringBuilder.append("\"");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you too! But Darshan Mehta is a bit shorter and I'm using Java 8 so lambda is no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try something like this

for (int i=0;i<stylingParams.size();i++){

            String test=stylingParams.toString();

            String modified=test.substring(test.indexOf("{")+1,test.lastIndexOf("}"));
            String mod1=modified.replaceAll("=", ":");
            String mod2=mod1.replaceAll(",", ";");


            System.out.println("\"style\"="+mod2);
        }
```